# Combine tables postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to combine two tables in postgres - people and meetings. Each meeting can have multiple people. As a summary:

```
create table People (
    id              serial,
...
    primary key (id)
);

create table Meets (
    id  serial,
...
    primary key (id)
);

create table MeetsPeople (
    meets_id integer references Meets(id),
    people_id integer references People(id),
    primary key(meets_id,people_id)
);
```

Is there a way to keep the meeting content but combine the people_ids (or even better all the info in the people table) into one attribute? An example output is below, l am basically looking to merge record 1 and 2, keeping the common attributes to notes and then keeping unique values for the people attributes.

[image]

Or am l best off just returning two seperate tables and combining this in the backend logic?

Hopefully that makes sense...

Comment: Show us some example rows, and your desired result. That will clarify what you want, and you might find the answer yourself.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.